# In Highcharts, how to create glow/shadow effect inside solidgauge?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, highcharts

I'm trying to implement some sort of a glow effect inside the gauge, but can only achieve it on the outside. I was also trying to add the glow effect on a circle/background inside the gauge, but it is hidden below the green/orange areas.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
    marginTop: 0
  },

  title: {
    text: false,
    style: {
      fontSize: '24px'
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'none',
    shadow: false,
    style: {
      fontSize: '16px'
    },
    pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span>',
    positioner: function(labelWidth) {
      return {
        x: 200 - labelWidth / 2,
        y: 180
      };
    }
  },

  pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360,
    background: [{
      outerRadius: '88%',
      innerRadius: '70%',
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      borderWidth: 0
    }]
  },

  plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
      animation: false,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      linecap: 'round',
      stickyTracking: false,
      rounded: true
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickPositions: []
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Something',
    data: [{
      color: '#e76a0b',
      radius: '112%',
      innerRadius: '88%',
      y: 100,
      borderColor: '#e76a0b'
    }, {
      color: '#007272',
      radius: '112%',
      innerRadius: '88%',
      y: 40,
      borderColor: '#007272'
    }]
  }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-series-group {
  filter: url(#glow)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
  <defs>
    <filter id="glow" x="-5000%" y="-5000%" width="10000%" height="10000%">
      <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="#000" flood-opacity=".2"></feFlood>
      <feComposite in="flood" result="mask" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="in"></feComposite>
      <feMorphology in="mask" result="dilated" operator="dilate" radius="3"></feMorphology>
      <feGaussianBlur in="dilated" result="blurred" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="blurred"></feMergeNode>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"></feMergeNode>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/remisture/f2srey6g/4/

Comment: It looks that instead of gradients you should be able to use activity gauge chart: http://jsfiddle.net/f2srey6g/

Comment: You could achieve similar effect by using a shadow image overlay with Renderer.image

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński, yes, implementing rounded corners is nice with your example. Your example was kind of hard to wrap my head around, though. It is not clear to me what your second series does. Is that even needed? http://jsfiddle.net/remisture/f2srey6g/3/

Comment: @stpoa, do you have an example?

Comment: Hi Remi, my second series is added because on your image both of your data points has visible ends. Without this series only one series will have visible ends. Check difference between this two examples:  http://jsfiddle.net/f2srey6g/ and http://jsfiddle.net/f2srey6g/5/

Comment: Ah, that makes sense :)

Comment: For shadow effect you can look at: https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/activity-gauge-svg-fill-formatting-t36612

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vzayj3db/ - simple example

Comment: That could work if I had a fixed graph size, but I need a solution supporting window resizing. Thanks, tho :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complete solution based on @GrzegorzBlachliński`s answer.

In order to create scalable shadow you can calculate its size based on the size of your chart in redraw and load event.

```
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
    marginTop: 50,
    events: {
        load () {
        const chart = this
        const el = document.querySelector('.highcharts-tracker > path.highcharts-point')
        const {x, y, width, height } = el.getBBox()

        chart.shadow = chart
        .renderer.image('http://i.imgur.com/frVkXOh.png', x+10, y+50, width, height)
        .attr({ zIndex: 10 })
        .add()
      },
        redraw () {
        const chart = this
        const el = document.querySelector('.highcharts-tracker > path.highcharts-point')
                const {x, y, width, height } = el.getBBox()

        chart.shadow.attr({ x: x+10, y: y + 50, width, height })
      }
    }
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Activity',
    style: {
      fontSize: '24px'
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'none',
    shadow: false,
    style: {
      fontSize: '16px'
    },
    pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span>',
    positioner: function(labelWidth) {
      return {
        x: 200 - labelWidth / 2,
        y: 180
      };
    }
  },

  pane: {
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 360,
    background: []
  },

  plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
      animation: false,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      linecap: 'round',
      stickyTracking: false,
      rounded: true
    }
  },

  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickPositions: []
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Something',
    data: [{
      color: '#e76a0b',
      radius: '112%',
      innerRadius: '88%',
      y: 100,
      borderColor: '#e76a0b'
    }, {
      color: '#007272',
      radius: '112%',
      innerRadius: '88%',
      y: 40,
      borderColor: '#007272'
    }]
  }]
})
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kumrruhq/